# Loops not recognizing variables?

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm new to C and working with CUDA although I don't think this problem is specific to CUDA - I've been able to transfer data to and from the GPU device without any problems and for testing purposes only working with a single thread.

After a long loop calculating f1 and f2, I have this snippet of code:

```
float price = 0;
float net = 0;
int numTrades = 0;

for (int j = 1; j < dataCol; j++) {
    if (((f1[j] > f2[j]) && (f1[j - 1] < f2[j - 1]) && price == 0)) {
            price = data[j];
            numTrades++;
    }
    else if (((f1[j] < f2[j]) && (f1[j - 1] > f2[j - 1]) && price != 0)) {
            net += data[j] - price;
            price = 0;
            numTrades++;
    }
}
```

which as far as I can tell doesn't have any problems, except for the fact that it refuses to compile with an "identifier 'price' is undefined" error coming from the first if statement. This snippet is the first place in my code it's mentioned and I've tried initializing with int, float, double, even boolean but still get the same error.

Anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Comment: Have you correctly finished the statement before `float price = 0;` line? Maybe it's wrong and it all becomes just one that fails for the compiler.

Comment: yep.. that's embarrassing, I have no idea why it didn't point me to the line above like it usually does. Thanks for the quick reply though.

Comment: Your're welcome @AltusVultur. Will post it as answer.

Comment: This is why self-contained examples are a good thing...

Answer (score 1):

Tl;dr if things inexplicably break in one location, look for typos above it ( I was missing a semicolon in the previous line. )

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** - Your code snippet looks ok.  Issue is most likely elsewhere in your actual code.

Once possible reason, however, as I see it, is your compiler does not support `C99` or above. Variable definition in between a function code (Mixed declaration) is allowed onwards `C99`. In other versions, it should come at the beginning of the function itself. Then, also, you should have received error in

```
 for(int j=1; j<
```

as this is also a `C99` feature, so my above assumption is not likely to be true.

Please show some more code.